# sticky menu gets stuck with google map

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sticky

i have a sticky menu that remains on the top of the screen when scrolled down to 100px, however on a page that i have a googlemap the sticky menu gets weird and stays on a input search form.. i have tried disabling js file that is integrated with the map however it didn't help, on other pages without the map the sticky menu works fine and with firefox even on the page where i have the map the sticky menu works fine too.. right now im on the verge of losing my mind what is wrong with chrome..

here's the page i'm having problem with
http://www.chemtools.com.au/find/
you'll have to scroll down and scroll back to the top to get the issue, on firefox it the issue doesn't shows up so my suspect is chrome itself..

any advise where i should look into or what could be causing the issue?

here is the js the is running the sticky menu`function sticky_menu() {

```
jQuery('.header').affix({
    offset: { top: jQuery('.sticky_menu').offset().top}
});

jQuery('.header-middle').affix({
    offset: { top: jQuery('.sticky_menu').offset().top+100}
});

jQuery('#logo').affix({
    offset: { top: jQuery('.sticky_menu').offset().top+100}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating your problem by using jQuery. You can easily stick it to the top of the screen using CSS.

If you wrap your header, logo, and and `.header-middle` objects in a div such as

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <!-- Your floating header goes here -->
</div>
```

Then set the wrapper's style/CSS to have `position: fixed;` ex:

```
#wrapper{
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
}
```

CSS's `position: fixed` attribute forced the object's location to be fixed to a set location on the screen, which will follow with the screen as the user scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

i sorted it out,, it is cause by -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);

i just set -webkit-transform: none; to only be applied on chrome and safari browser and the sticking issue with the map is gone..

thanks for the time @Aeolingamenfel looking into the problem,, i really appreciate it